# Does Firestore snapshost() listeners do an initial document read every data every time the app restarts?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When using `firestore` `snapshot()`, and set a listener, Cloud Firestore sends your listener an initial snapshot of the data, and then another snapshot each time the documents change.

However if I close the app, and reopen it, does firestore make a read on all the data it already has queried or is there an internal sync system (for example if they store documents metadata, like `updatedAt` they could only read documents that haven't been updated since x) ?

In other words. if I use `onSnapshot()` listener, I will make x documents read initially, then 1 document each time a document changes. My question is: If I close the app and a document changes, then when I open the app, is 1 read made or x + 1 ?

It is important for me because I have a bunch of initial calls and I'm wondering how that'd affect the cost($).

It's also important to know for data modeling and how it affects the cost.

Answer (score 4):

**Every** time you perform a new query against the server (this is the default), it will cost a read, and the documents will have to be transferred.  It will not use the cache unless there is no connection, or your specifically target the cache for the query.  Quitting and returning to the app doesn't change this behavior at all.

I suggest reading this: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firestore-clients-to-cache-or-not-to-cache-or-both-8f66a239c329

Comment: This article doesn't really answer the question. When you have a listener and 1 document changes you will only have 1 read.  If you set up an initial listener you have X document read (depending on how much are returned initially) + 1 read for each doc change. However if you have set up a listener already in the past before closing the app, it's not clear if it reread the initial data set or not. They could very well use sync metadata to do it, like it's usually done in offline first dbs.

Comment: In other words. if I use `snapshots` listener, I will receive x documents initially, then 1 document each time a document changes. My question is: If I close the app and 1 document changes, then when I open the app, is 1 read made or x + 1 ?

Comment: I have borrowed your answer here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/421573/148725

Comment: further more snapshots listener doesn't let you provide a source. so the article is a bit irrelevant to my question. Although it seems to answer the one of Jonathan so that's nice.

Comment: The article is not intended to answer the question - the text provided here answers the question.  The article is provided to add information about how the caching system actually works, since that's the only thing that can prevent the cost of a read any time a query is made.  It's not clear to me what you mean by "x + 1" reads.  A document read is just a simple read operation.  It is no more complex than that.  Documents don't retain a history the causes more reads to happen.  They only ever have current state.

Comment: You are not understanding because we are talking about different things, that's all. I'm talking about listening to a collection, not a single document. Say I'm watching all restaurants in the restaurants collection and there are 100 restaurants. It will cost 100 reads initially. Then someone makes an update on one restaurant, that is a total of 101 reads. Now if I close the application and come back but nothing has changed on the db, does firestore retrieve all the documents again for a total of 201 reads, or will it only incur one read that sees that nothing has changed, totaling 102 reads ?

Comment: That is my question, and that is why I didn't accept the answer yet. In an in house system we did at my previous company we didn't retransfer the dataset that didn't change, so it's possible google wouldn't either

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of listener

`OnChange()` will read only when data changes

`addListenerForSingleValueEvent` will check just once, and if it is the `onCreate` section, it will be executed immediately

`addValueEventListener` will keep checking constantly, but will log as a read only if the data changes